# Surface between contour lines in 3D

Tags: matlab, 3d, contour

I have code like this:

```
load('something.mat');
[X,Y] = meshgrid(tx,ty);

tt1 = U_TV1(:,:,1);
tt2=U_TV1( :,:,2);
tt3=U_TV1( :,:,3);

figure(2);
% surf(X, Y, tt1, 'FaceAlpha', 0.3);
shading interp;
hold on;
e = [1 3]; % [ .001  .1 .3  1  3 10 ]; % epsilon
[c1, h1] = contour3(X, Y, tt1, e, 'r');
[c2, h2] = contour3(X, Y, tt2, e, 'b');
[c3, h3] = contour3(X, Y, tt3, e, 'g');
% legend('k=1', 'k=2', 'k=3');
clabel(c1, h1, e, 'fontsize', 10, 'fontweight', 'bold');
clabel(c2, h2, e, 'fontsize', 10, 'fontweight', 'bold');
clabel(c3, h3, e, 'fontsize', 10, 'fontweight', 'bold');
zlim([0 15]);
```

And the result is following 3D plot:

[image: Plot from Matlab]

How I can fill space (draw surface) between contours with the same number ?

I would like to have something like this (made with Paint):

[image: Output I want]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide some representative data instead of "something.mat"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution consists out of two steps:

1. Extract the points/lines through which you want to fit a plot
2. Fit a surface through that points using [`fit`](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html)

Comment: @PeterJung Note that you may consider posting your implementation of this approach as a separate answer, which may be useful for others.